# linq to sql domain context not visible to domain service class

Tags: linq-to-sql, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm creating a silverlight 4 application (using the Business Application template).  I generated Linq to SQL classes for my tables in the .web project and want to use RIA services.  When I add the domain service class to the .web project the data context for the Linq to SQL classes isn't available to choose.

According to the documentation creating the Linq to SQL classes and building the project is all that is required.  This works if I try using Entity Framework classes but not Linq to SQL.  There are several examples available using Linq to SQL and none mention any other requirements.

I have tried several projects, VB, C#, different computers, the result has been the same.

Thanks for any advice on how to get this working!

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer, you must install the **RIA Services Toolkit** as a separate install. The standard Silverlight and RIA Services installation does not include the `LinqToSql` Domain Context, which the Toolkit adds. See [WCF RIA Services Toolkit Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19663).

Comment: I had this same problem, though I already had the toolkit installed.  It took an uninstall, restart, then reinstall of the latest toolkit (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26939)in order to fix it